# ajax modalpopup extender showing data from server on show

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, ajax.net

Perhaps my understanding of the Ajax Modal popup is not correct. What I would like to do is to retrieve some data from the server and show it on the modal pop up when the user clicks on a button on the page. The following code is in the aspx of the page.

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlDetail" CssClass="modal" runat="server">

             <div class="header">
               Data
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                 <div class="header">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblInput" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                   </div>  
            </div> 


   </asp:Panel>

   <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeDetail" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlDetail" PopupControlID="pnlDetail" TargetControlID="hdnDetail"

    BackgroundCssClass="modalBG" CancelControlID="ShowDetailClose" runat="server" />
```

In the button click event of a button on the page, I retrieve the data from the server and assign the value to the lblInput inside the pop up panel and call mpe.Show.. but it does not display the value. I'm assuming the data needs to be present on load of mpe but thats not what I have to do.

If MPE cannot achieve this, what is the alternative?

Comment: do you show your modal popup from code behind?

Comment: yes. Since I have to retrieve the data from the server, i call mpe.Show in the button_Click event.

Comment: is the modal popup in an update panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Put the above panel inside an update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlDetail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>

..... <asp:panel .. > ajax mpe control etc (what I have in the question)..

   </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then in the button click, call the following.

UserControl.LoadData(object dataContents); (user control has the popup data. It does not have to be user control. Bind your controls here with data).

updPnlDetail.Update();
mpe.Show();

The data will show. I guess the updatepanel's update method does a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the dragpanel extender, because I had some problems with the modal popup too. But here is a possible solution with the modal popup:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/08/14/populating-a-modalpopupextender-dynamically.aspx

Comment: The problem is that I have to pass in multiple key values and bring back at least 15 values.

Comment: you can try the dynamic modalpopup described in the blog or combine a dragpanel with the ajax resizable control.